# Excel: If a cell in a row is equal to the cell underneath it, concatenate the contents of the cells

Tags: excel

If A2 is equal to A3, I want to concatenate the contents of R2 and R3.

For example,

[image]

In the above image, I would like to concatenate the cells R4 and R5 so it says "The Sarah + File Folder".
Same with "The Broke + File Folder"

Sometimes there are rows like these: [image]

Where 3 line items are equal to each other. In this case I would like to concat all 3 rows so it appears like "The Sarah + Cork Strip + File Folder"

Order of concatenation does not matter as much to me, but if it could have line item that starts with "The" first that would be great but im not sure if that is possible.

This is what I created originally but it did not work right as it only worked for the first item:

=IF(A2=A3,CONCAT(R2,R3))

I've been stuck on this all day so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The formula below should do what you want. Please try it in any cell of row 2 and copy down from there.

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A$2:A$10000,A2)>1,COUNTIF(A$2:A$10000,A2)=COUNTIF(A2:A$10000,A2)), INDIRECT("R" & ROW()) & " " & INDIRECT("R" & ROW()+1) & IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$10000,A2)>2, " " & INDIRECT("R" & ROW()+2), ""), "")
```

The row ID must be in the range A2:A$10000. The end is an arbitrary high number, the start presumes one caption row. When you change the range pay attention to the difference between A2:A$10000 and A$2:A$10000. It's this extra $ sign that prevents the formula from writing in the rows in which the second and third match is found.

Data must be sorted on the column with the row ID (column A in my example). It will identify the correct row to concatenate even if the list isn't sorted but it will concatenate the text found in column R with that in the next row(s) from where it writes. I suppose it wouldn't be too difficult to expand the formula to ensure matching rows but it would grow in size quite substantially. I think, sorting is the better value for effort.